# Median error propagation

Tags: error, median, error-propagation

Assuming we have a set of measurements $x_i, i=1,\dots,N$ each with an error of $\Delta x_i$, I then normalize the data by the median of $x$. Can an error for the median value be calculated with the goal of estimating the errors in the values of $x_i /  \operatorname{med}(\mathbf x)$ ?

Comment: It comes down to what you might mean by "an error for the median value" as well as what exactly the "error" in a measurement means or measures.  Could you elaborate on these?

Comment: Sure! My goal is to normalize the xi values by the the median value of x. Since each xi comes with a standard deviation (from the instrument, environment, etc.), I'm afraid of assuming a "perfect" median when propagating the errors for the new values.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to estimate the errors in the values $x_i/\operatorname{med}(\mathbf x)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly thank you!